# Can we have a way to write primary key for a table, where a new primary key could be added in middle?

Tags: sql, primary-key

My table is for inspection

inspection

ID    : int
Inspection_ desc : nvarchar

[Data]

[image: 1]

My webpage is showing, three Security, Health and Dental; proper order requirement
My concern is if in future I add " Criminal : Inspection" and the order required is Security, Criminal,Health and Dental.

How does that work with the primary key and what type shall I be using.

This is my first ever database project after school, so just looking for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

then to have a bullet proof solution , add a new column as int for order:

```
alter table add column ordercol int
```

and you always order by that column

```
select * from table
order by ordercol;
```

Answer (score 0):

A Primary Key is an id to identify an individual row. And usually a numeric id due to performance, How your system internally identifies the row is related to, but not necessarily the same as, how your inspection identify themselves.

> A primary key is a column or a set of columns in a table whose values
> uniquely identify a row in the table. A relational database is
> designed to enforce the uniqueness of primary keys by allowing only
> one row with a given primary key value in a table.

what are you looking for is to have an new column which identify the **order**.

- id, description, order
- 1 , Security   , 1
- 2 , Health     , 2
- 3 , Dental     , 4
- 4 , Criminal   , 3

Comment: Thats the idea, I am going with. What if, in future I want disable a check but not affect the other table with the pass/fail results. But just do no want to show for example, Dental anymore. is there a way around than deleting it, within database